# How can I read document lines of XML file in PHP by using loop?

Tags: php, xml

How can I read document lines of XML file in PHP by using loop?
Let me show you an example, 
This is XML tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GRPO>    
<Goods>
<CardCode>V10000</CardCode>
<DocDueDate>07/11/2016</DocDueDate>
<GoodsLines>
   <Line>
      <ItemNo>A00003</ItemNo>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>4000</UnitPrice>
   </Line>
   <Line>
      <ItemNo>A00004</ItemNo>
      <Quantity>5</Quantity>
      <UnitPrice>5000</UnitPrice>
   </Line>
</GoodsLines>
</Goods>        
</GRPO>
```

The PHP codes of to read the XML file

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("GRPO.xml");
foreach($xml->children() as $Line)
{
echo"$Line->ItemNo";
echo"$Line->Quantity";
echo"$Line->UnitPrice";
}
?>
```

The problem here is no data are displayed.
What can I do in my codes in order to print out values of lines by using loop?

Please anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not accessing the correct level of the XML. The `children()` method only accesses *direct* children of the document, so you're only iterating over the **Goods** node.

Your loop needs to look something like this:

```
foreach ($xml->Goods->GoodsLines->Line as $Line)
{
    echo $Line->ItemNo;
    echo $Line->Quantity;
    echo $Line->UnitPrice;
}
```